# Is ReCaptcha unnecessary for resetting password?

Tags: strapi

I have an organizational question: 
would it make sense to install ReCaptcha for "Reset Password"?
so to post:

```
{ 
  password: "123456789", 
  passwordConfirmation: "123456789", 
  token: "tokenblabla...", 
  captcha: "captchablabla..."
}
```

I think the token alone will be enough, right?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

By default, Strapi is standalone without dependencies of another service.

So I don't think we will add something like this into the project.

After that, you can easily add this to your own application.

You will have to first add your captcha in your front end application to get the token.

And then you will have to customize the reset password function using the [customization concept](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/customization.html)

Here is [the function](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/controllers/Auth.js#L180) you will have to update to add you ReCapcha validation code.